# How to implement google recaptcha with swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I've created rest API in lumen using [This wrapper](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume) for which I'm using google hidden reCaptcha on my web panel but I wanted to know if I can implement it on swagger too?

Comment: By "Swagger", do you mean Swagger UI? Or some [other Swagger project](https://swagger.io/open-source-integrations/)?

Comment: Swagger ui only I've added the wrapper I'm using